# when to close database in Android

Tags: android

I have read several "answers" but couldn't find a definitive answer.

I have an app that does DB operations using AsyncTask's, so it could execute in any one of the threads in the pool. I also have a background thread to perform data sync-ing (long running operation)

Which pattern should I use?

PAttern 1: Open and close for every operation, Example:

```
db = SQLiteOpenHelper.getWriteableDatabase()
// Do some operations such as insert / select ...
db.close();
```

Pattern 2: Open once in app startup, share between all threads and close at app termination, Example:

```
Application: 
public void onCreate(){ .. open database and cache the instance ... }
```

Pattern 3: Implement some form of reference counting to detect when all references to a cached instance is released. (I thought Android already implemented this originally, but I was wrong)

I've seen the code for `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWriteableDatabase()`, it returns the same instance if it is not closed. So for pattern 1, 2 threads can obtain the same instance, and one thread could be closing  the instance when another thread is performing an operation. This results in "library routine executed out of sequence" in my app.
 Pattern 1 also seems overkill for opening and closing multiple times.

Pattern 2 seems safer, but how to detect when app terminates? There doesn't seem to be a reliable way. What happens when a database is not closed when app terminates?

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of research and testing, I have come to the conclusion that closing the local SQlite database is not really necessary. I use a singleton `SQliteOpenHelper` as below :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    private static MyApplication instance;
    public MyApplication(){
        instance = this;
    }
    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance;
    }
}

public class LocalDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "LocalDBHelper";

    private static LocalDBHelper instance = null;
    /*private constructor to avoid direct instantiation by other classes*/
    private LocalDBHelper(){
        super(MyApplication.getContext(), DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    /*synchronized method to ensure only 1 instance of LocalDBHelper exists*/
    public static synchronized LocalDBHelper getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new LocalDBHelper();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

I get the database by `LocalDBHelper.getInstance().getWritableDatabase()`.

The key point here is that this ensures thread safety and avoids the need to constantly open and close the database for every operation. Only one instance of the database exists at any point in time during the lifetime of the app. It does not generate any errors/warnings.